# Sort and merge in a array

Tags: php, arrays

I have trouble in handle array PHP, I have an array:

```
[0] {
'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
'meta' => {
          'product' => {
                        'id' => '1',
                        'content' => 'This is content'
                       }
          }
}
[1] {
'email' => 'test2@gmail.com',
'meta' => {
          'product' => {
                        'id' => '2',
                        'content' => 'This is content'
                       }
          }
}
[2] {
'email' => 'test2@gmail.com',
'meta' => {
          'product' => {
                        'id' => '3',
                        'content' => 'This is content'
                       }
          }
}
```

I need to merge this array by value `'email'`, like this:

```
[0] {
    'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
    'meta' => {
              'product' => {
                            'id' => '1',
                            'content' => 'This is content'
                           }
              }
    }
[1] {
    'email' => 'test2@gmail.com',
    'meta' => {
              'product' => [0] {
                                 'id' => '2',
                                 'content' => 'This is content'
                           }
                           [1] {
                                 'id' => '3',
                                 'content' => 'This is content'
                               }
              }
    }
```

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Please post the code which you tried, so helping you will be easy!

Comment: For merging you can loop your array, find email value, 
check if this email is a key in tmpArr, if no
add it into tmpArray[email] = curr[meta][product];
if exists add to this tmpArr[email][meta][product][] = array_pop(curr[meta][product]) 

Where curr its your current iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sorted_array = [];
$emails = [];
$i = 0;
foreach ($arr as $array) {
    if(!empty($array['email']) && !empty($array['meta']['product'])){
        if( in_array($array['email'], $emails)){
            $i--;
        } else {
            $emails[] = $array['email'];
        }
        $sorted_array[$i]['email'] = $array['email'];
        $sorted_array[$i]['meta']['product'][] = $array['meta']['product'];
        $i++;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($sorted_array);
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Php has many function to sort an Array. You can consult the documentation to choice the better algorithms to your case http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php. And you can merge result Arrays with array_merge function, like it:

> array_merge($a1,$a2)

I created an example for your code here:

> http://codepad.org/zzkndGQZ

Answer (score 0):

You can use the email like array's key, to end, use array_combine to have indeces since 0 to N number...

```
<?php

$oldArray = array(
    array(
        'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
        'meta' => array(
            'product' => array(
                       'id' => '1',
                        'content' => 'This is content'
            )
        )
    ), array(
        'email' => 'test2@gmail.com',
        'meta' => array(
            'product' => array(
                        'id' => '2',
                        'content' => 'This is content'
            )
        )
    ), array(
        'email' => 'test2@gmail.com',
        'meta' => array(
          'product' => array(
                        'id' => '3',
                        'content' => 'This is content'
            )
        )
    )
);


$newArray = array();
foreach($oldArray as $element){
    if(isset($newArray[$element['email']])) {
        if(!isset($newArray[$element['email']]['meta']['product'][0]))
            $newArray[$element['email']]['meta']['product'] = array($newArray[$element['email']]['meta']['product']);
        $newArray[$element['email']]['meta']['product'][] = $element['meta']['product'];
    } else {
        $newArray[$element['email']] = $element;
    }
}


//For index since 0 to n    
print_r(array_combine(range(0,count($newArray)-1), $newArray));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can build a new array with the sorted informations.

It should be working with something like this, but not tested:

```
$sorted_array = [];
$i = 0;
foreach ($unsorted_array as $array) {
    if(!empty($array['email']) && !empty($array['meta']['product'])){
        $sorted_array[$i]['email'] = $array['email'];
        $sorted_array[$i]['meta']['product'][] = $array['meta']['product'];
        $i++;
    }
}

print_r($sorted_array);
```